# Alert Event Listener depends on the option selected JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick, dom-events, onchange

I'm learning about JS events and put them int HTML. I'm doing

```js
var myCountriesSelect = document.querySelector("#mySelect");

function init() {
  var countries = ['USA', 'France', 'Italy', 'Brazil', 'Colombia', 'Belize', 'Venezuela'];
  for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    var opt = countries[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.innerHTML = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    myCountriesSelect.appendChild(el);
  }
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  text-indent: 0.01px;
  text-overflow: '';
  padding: 1em 0 1em 1em;
  border: 1px solid #107177;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: relative;
  border-right-width: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

select:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #169ca4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
</head>

<body onload="init();">
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option value="-1">Select your country</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

This exercise but I don't know how to add a event listener that fires an alert with the country selected in the select List.

The Instructions are:

1. Use the innerHTML property to add all these countries into the `#mySelect` select.
2. Then, add a listener to the 'change' event and display and alert with the selected country when the user selects it.

Comment: [`myCountriesSelect.addEventListener("change",function() {...})`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

Comment: I also recommend to use addEventListener on the window instead of inline on the body tag: `window.addEventListener("load",() => {const sel = document.getElementById("mySelect"); sel.addEventListener("change",e => console.log(e.currentTarget.value)); sel.innerHTML += ['USA', 'France', 'Italy', 'Brazil', 'Colombia', 'Belize', 'Venezuela'] .map(country => new Option(country,country).outerHTML)})`

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation @mplungjan but the exercise ask me to do in that way because the HTML is already done

Comment: I did not change any HTML. If there is a body onload on the HTML, then it is poor teaching

Comment: I know that the best way in real life and in a job is putting that in JS instead in HTML inline, but this is a gradual exercise for begginer from repl.it platform and the HTML came predefined.

Comment: Ok. Then my first comment is answering the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the code as follows :-

```
var myCountriesSelect = document.querySelector("#mySelect");

function init() {
  var countries = ['USA', 'France', 'Italy', 'Brazil', 'Colombia', 'Belize', 'Venezuela'];
  for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    var opt = countries[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.innerHTML = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    myCountriesSelect.appendChild(el);
  }
}

myCountriesSelect.addEventListener("change", function(event){
  alert(event.target.value)
});
```

Comment: Either use querySelector OR getElementById, not both in the same lines of code. DRY. Anyway already answered in the comments and is a dupe

Comment: Also `alert(event.target.value)` can be written `alert(this.value)` when you use function

Answer (score 0):

Answering to get a few things straight.

Answer: Use [change event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

1. move the myCountriesSelect into the init function so it is not accessed before it is available
2. use `myCountriesSelect.addEventListener("change",function() { alert(this.value); });` to alert

```js
function init() {
  var myCountriesSelect = document.querySelector("#mySelect");
  var countries = ['USA', 'France', 'Italy', 'Brazil', 'Colombia', 'Belize', 'Venezuela'];
  for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    var opt = countries[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.innerHTML = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    myCountriesSelect.appendChild(el);
  }
  myCountriesSelect.addEventListener("change",function() { alert(this.value); });

}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  text-indent: 0.01px;
  text-overflow: '';
  padding: 1em 0 1em 1em;
  border: 1px solid #107177;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: relative;
  border-right-width: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

select:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #169ca4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
</head>

<body onload="init();">
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option value="-1">Select your country</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Better answer:

1. Remove the inline event handler
2. don't repeat yourself
3. add the load event handler so the elements exist before using

```js
const countries = ['USA', 'France', 'Italy', 'Brazil', 'Colombia', 'Belize', 'Venezuela'];
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const sel = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  // arrow functions do not have "this" so use event.currentTarget
  sel.addEventListener("change", e => console.log(e.currentTarget.value));
  sel.innerHTML += countries.map(country => new Option(country, country).outerHTML)
})
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  text-indent: 0.01px;
  text-overflow: '';
  padding: 1em 0 1em 1em;
  border: 1px solid #107177;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: relative;
  border-right-width: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

select:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #169ca4;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="-1">Select your country</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan I have trying this way and it does not work as I want.
After selected any country it does not fire an alert window with the name of this country selected

Comment: I use console.log in my second example. The first example does use alert

Comment: See my first example. It fully answers your question without changing your code substantially